# scope in routes not working with Cucumber/Capybara, default scope parameter not working in WEBrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, cucumber, capybara

I have this route to separate users of different agencies:

```
scope "/:agency" do
  resources :users
end
```

In ApplicationController I've added this behavior to default_url_options:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { :agency => params[:agency] }
end
```

Everything looks ok with the server and params[:agency] reports what's in the URL.
But while testing with Cucumber + Capybara

```
user_path(1)
```

becomes

```
http://www.example.com/1/users
```

instead of

```
http://www.example.com/theagency/users/1
```

Reading a bit of documentation I tried this:

```
scope "/:agency", :defaults => { :agency => 'test-agency'} do
  resources :users
end
```

The tests appear to be working (the URL are built correctly) but in fact all URLs are built with test-agency as the first parameter, whatever the parameter is.

Any idea to have the tests work with this setup?